# Character class and race comparisons between Warhammer 40k and D&D 5e

Tags: dnd-5e, class, warhammer-40k, wrath-and-glory

I play Dnd 5e with a group of friends and we are longtime dnd players,  but one of our friends has been obsessed with Warhammer for several years. We've decided to try it, particularly the Warhammer 40k RPG.

It seems like a pretty complex game. I think the problem  is that none of us knows anyone who has ever played it firsthand. I've been watching YouTube videos, the obsessed friend made a little rpg game, two guys in the group have been pouring over the latest "rulebook" and trying games at night, and occasionally, five of us have tried playing altogether.  Unfortunately, it's a comedy of errors each time because we decide the rules work differently each time and it never seems right. But anyway, it's all in fun.

Here's my question: the races seem extremely different between D&D and the Warhammer 40k RPG game and I'm having trouble finding any similarity  between any of the classes. Does anyone know how any races or classes compare between the two games? For example, would a Space Marine in the Warhammer 40k RPG game be something like  a paladin in dnd 5e?

Anyone know?

Comment: Specifically which version of 40K rpg are we talking about? Dark Heresy (1e or 2e), Wrath and Glory?

Comment: Wrath and Glory - sorry about that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## You just can't compare the two

D&D is, by and large, generic fantasy. Each of the worlds has some specific flavor or flavors but it is intended to be setting where the main characters are heroes expected to triumph over the odds.

Warhammer 40K is a grim, dark setting where each individual tends to have about as much worth as a grain of sand on a beach. Life is cheap and death is frequent, especially against the kind of enemies you are likely to be up against. A space marine for example is vaguely akin to a paladin, except like all humans in the 40K setting, they regard just about all non-human lifeforms as enemies to be purged out of existence. Warhammer 40K is also more focused around technology rather than magic. The closest equivalent to magic are the warp powers of the psykers. Except psykers tend to be extremely distrusted since they are a) considered to be mutants and b) might get possessed by a warp demon when they try to use their powers.

At best you can look for same archetypes in each, but the game mechanics are very different.

Comment: That's really a very helpful answer and I appreciate it. I was getting that impression already, particularly since equipment is such a big deal in the Warhammer game. When technology is so important, it makes sense that equipment is a big deal. Also, I've been thinking of psykers as warped pseudo-sorcerers.